# Why does this recursive type definition require primitives to be defined?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why does this not compile if I remove the commented lines on this type?

```js
type DeepPartial<T> =
    T extends Array<any> ? T
    : T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? T
    : T extends Function ? T
    : T extends number ? T // why is this needed
    : T extends string ? T // same thing...
    : T extends boolean ? T // same thing...
    : T extends bigint ? T // same thing...
    : T extends symbol ? T // same thing...
    : T extends object ? { [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]> }
    : T;

function test<T>(o: DeepPartial<T>) {
    if (o === 1) return 0;
    if (o === '') return 1;
    if (o === false) return 2;
    if (o === 1n) return 3;
    if (o === Symbol.hasInstance) return 4;
    if (typeof o === 'number' && o === 2) return 5; //or this needed?
    return 6;
}
```

I think the commented lines on the DeepPartial type should be unnecessary because of the final condition but the compiler disagrees ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8AUFJVPlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QCCqqyIuyJiGIB+ahSoAuarQbN2UAEoRkLAPZNsIbr36DhUMfgmVpNeo1YcAYgFcmAY0wbD4qlDOzLCprYC2AEYQqK40APRhUADuABYgUBgcwDGJUEzwLBAsJh4yFvIcbMCoGEwA5qFQEVBsyH7QyaVlAHStOZ75VlABamrYKkyV1bX1UI3lrc3teXJdARhlpcBDkSMNKRNt7h2zCmwggX0rNXXrTZPT5rscAN4Avq43UADaiAmDANYQIGoAZtQAXRE0jgCBQ6CweHwrwBxDulwA3GQyL97E4MC5GEUCIQABRqEHwJBoTA4HEASigNxyGH++NIJBIUAAjJTUBBgLZUIMAAxI9y0qD0xlMgDkorZHK5g2Z-KoguFjKgvxwbAgks53KgACY5ZQFWoGUzmUwNdKoABmPUJOmGkVQADKBx62GaMWQbAAkkwioIHOqoOzNYMACzWhWgSB-KB2pWi3yBYKiqAAMhTMaNOrNWoArAiqmE1CFGhx0lksiIckHzQA2JHwoA)).

Comment: In addition, calling `test(false)` does not produce a compile error even when those lines are commented out.

Comment: yeah I can call the function with any of the values and it doesn't produce a compile time error, and the compiler knows that the return type in this case is `false`  if the body of the function is changed to `return o;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error message is

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'DeepPartial<T>' and '[number|string|boolean|bigint|symbol]' have no overlap.

This is very similar for the error message you'd get for all but the last `if` statement when defining the function as `function test<T>(o: T)`:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T' and '[number|string|boolean|bigint|symbol]' have no overlap.

Because the type has not been discriminated first, type `T` is an opaque type within the body of `test()`, so it must be treated like `unknown` rather than `any`.

It's not typical for `T` to refer to a non-homogeneous mixture of types, so if that's what you need, this is probably the approach I'd suggest:

```
const enum Test {
  ONE,
  STRING,
  FALSE,
  BIG_ONE,
  HAS_INSTANCE,
  TWO,
  UNKNOWN
}

type TestMap<T> = T extends 1 ? Test.ONE
  : T extends '' ? Test.STRING
  : T extends false ? Test.FALSE
  : T extends 1n ? Test.BIG_ONE
  : T extends SymbolConstructor['hasInstance'] ? Test.HAS_INSTANCE
  : T extends 2 ? Test.TWO
  : Test.UNKNOWN;

function test<T>(o: T): TestMap<T> {
  function testImpl(o: any): Test {
    if (o === 1) return Test.ONE;
    if (o === '') return Test.STRING;
    if (o === false) return Test.FALSE;
    if (o === 1n) return Test.BIG_ONE;
    if (o === Symbol.hasInstance) return Test.HAS_INSTANCE;
    if (o === 2) return Test.TWO;
    return Test.UNKNOWN;
  }

  return testImpl(o) as TestMap<T>;
}
```